# Запустить winrar из java

Tags: java

Как в коде вызвать winrar, разархивировать нужный файл, продолжить выполнение кода? Код копирует, удаляет, архивирует  файлы.
Команда в cmd выглядит так
"c:\Program Files\winrar\rar.exe" x "c:\temp\folder.rar" "C:\temp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправил кавычки. Работает.
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("d:/temp/rar.exe x d:/temp/folder.rar d:/temp/newfolder");

Answer (score 0):

Код не проверял, но так можно отправить команду в консоль

```
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\Program Files\winrar\rar.exe" x "c:\temp\folder.rar" "C:\temp");
```

Comment: Экранируйте слэши или поверните их, например `"c:\\Program Files\\winrar\\rar.exe"`